# Gregorian Calendar Adding Days and Printing

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a simple calendar app. In general, I want to print the calendar in month view. I am able to find the day and position of the first day of the month. After that, I want to add a day to the calendar and print the next day until I have printed all the days of that month. However, when I add one to the calendar, I don't get 2 (first day is 1), I get 9. Could someone please let me know why it's doing that. Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

enum MONTHS
{
    January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December;
}
enum DAYS
{
    Su, Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa;
}
public class MyCalendarTester {

    static GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); // capture today

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MONTHS[] arrayOfMonths = MONTHS.values();
        DAYS[] arrayOfDays = DAYS.values();
        System.out.println("    " + arrayOfMonths[cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1] + " " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)); //prints the month and year

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfDays.length; i++){
            if(i == 0){
                System.out.print(arrayOfDays[i]);
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(" " + arrayOfDays[i]);
            }
        }//print days of week

        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfDays.length; i++){
            if(!arrayOfDays[i].equals(arrayOfDays[cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1])){
                System.out.println("  ");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(" " + Calendar.getInstance().getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                break;
            }
        }

        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        System.out.println("  " + cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
        System.out.println("I think we're done here!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `GregorianCalendar()` constructor without any arguments constructs an instance of the `GregorianCalendar` class for *todays date*. In your code you use this constructor:

```
static GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); // capture today
```

The day of the month, at the time of posting in 8. `8+1=9`

---

To create a GregorianCalendar with the day of the month initialized to 1 you need to use `GregorianCalendar(int year,int month,int dayOfMonth)`. As stated in the javadocs, this constructor

> Constructs a GregorianCalendar with the given date set in the default time zone with the default locale.

```
static GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2015,5,1);
```

Comment: But how can I go about doing that without hard coding it? I want my calendar to know the real date today, figure out what the first day of the month way (day of the week to place 1 there) and then increment through by adding 1 to it until I print all the days of the month. Is there a way to do this without manipulating the calendar into thinking its a different date today?

Comment: @aurora91 You create one instance representing the current date `GregorianCalendar today = new GregorianCalendar()` and another that represents the first day of the current month `GregorianCalendar dayCounter = new GregorianCalendar();dayCounter.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1)` then call `dayCounter.roll(DAY_OF_MONTH,true)` until `today.equals(dayCounter)`.

Answer (score 1):

The calendar object you're adding one to is `static GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();` - that's why it said 9 (it is March, 9th)

Comment: It's still the 8th :p

Comment: So I removed the static modifier and placed the declaration of the Gregorian Calendar inside main. I assume that I am adding the days correctly, but now my question is, how can I print the day relative to what was added? If I try to print the date after adding, it still ends up printing today's date.